# Get raw request in Node.js

Tags: node.js

I'm building an echo server in Node.js for testing. I need access to the **raw** HTTP request (including headers). Is there a way to directly read the HTTP data, or is the only option to reconstruct the request using parsed headers and content?

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP module (and wrapping frameworks like `connect` and `express`), expose two objects when handling requests. Those two objects are passed to the callback of the request. In the case of `express` for example:

```
app.get('/', function(request, response) {
```

That first argument is the request objects, which holds everything (from headers to status code to body to a lot of other stuff).

Review the documentation for your specific module, to see how it's done in each one.

Comment: I know about that, how is it suposed to help with my problem?

Comment: @user2486570 If you know that, just respond with the data you need. Please [edit] your original question to clarify what your problem is.

Comment: But when I wait for data with `request.on('data', fn)`, I only get body of the request and all the headers are missing. I need the full request, including headers.

Comment: Yes, but `request` has other fields than `on`, the headers are there too... inspect the `request` object.

Comment: I know that headers are there too. I could reconstruct the request using `request.headers`, but I could never be sure it is actual request.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of testing your application using an "echo" server, I recommend that you use the [nock](http://npmjs.org/package/nock) module.

It allows you to:

- Prevent real network operations from happening (preferred in tests)
- Test if a request conforms to expectations
- Respond to that request with a custom-defined response, including custom headers

And much more. In practice, this should be much faster than spawning an actual HTTP server. It also keeps your test codebase cleaner and easier to understand because the behaviour of the responses is defined alongside your requests and other relevant logic.

As a real-world example, take a look at [google-api-nodejs-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client) which uses **Nock** to test if the client responds correctly to a server's response, i.e. it generates valid data when a valid JSON response is received, it triggers errors when a 400 HTTP status code is encountered etc. All that with the help of Nock.

Comment: But I need the server to test my CLIENT, not the server itself.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the purpose of that. With nock, you first tell it that when your application performs `GET` on `/api/users`, it should receive a JSON object along with a 200 response code. Then you take your application, perform the call and test that the response has been handled properly. I will update my answer with a very similar use case as yours from a real world...